# Scheme already exists: Bearer

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, bearer-token, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

I'm implementing login using Microsoft provider also implement the default login using jwt

when I run the project I got this error

> Scheme already exists: Bearer

when i comment this part, project run successfully

```
 //.AddJwtBearer(x =>
           // {
           //     x.SaveToken = true;
           //     x.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
           // })
```

here is my code

```
            var jwtSettings = new JWTSettings();
            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Secret)),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                RequireExpirationTime = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true
            };
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            })
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(configuration, "AzureAd")
                  .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                      .AddMicrosoftGraph(configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                         .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Why is there that exception?

Answer (score 0):

> Scheme already exists: Bearer

It means you have more than one schemes with the same name.

You can try to set the parameter `authenticationScheme` into `JwtBearerExtensions.AddJwtBearer Method`.Here is the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.jwtbearerextensions.addjwtbearer?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

And if you want to select the scheme,you can refer to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0#selecting-the-scheme-with-the-authorize-attribute),and try to use:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = xxx)]
```

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on exactly how/why here. Checking the docs didn't provide me with the clarity. Where's the second schema with the same name coming from, exactly? Perhaps it's obvious but I simply fail to see it. In the `AddAuthentication(...)`, I pass the name of the (first?) scheme. Where's the other one specified?